# how to parse a website if the url of the search request is changing

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, python-requests, html-parsing

I have a stock website that I want to parse some content to a csv file for now. I'm using Python requests HTML or beautifulsoap.

The problem is the URL is changing.
the website https://www.tadawul.com.sa/

an example of a stock: https://www.tadawul.com.sa/wps/portal/tadawul/market-participants/issuers/issuers-directory/company-details/!ut/p/z1/**04_Sj9CPykssy0xPLMnMz0vMAfIjo8zi_Tx8nD0MLIy83V1DjA0czVx8nYP8PI0MDAz0I4EKzBEKDEJDLYEKjJ0DA11MjQzcTfXDCSkoyE7zBAC-SKhH**/?companySymbol=*6002*

This "04_Sj9CPykssy0xPLM...."  is periodically changing.
why is it changing? how can I parse the webpage?

I found [the same data in the page source](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qFSk6.png)

is there a better way to parse pages in this website?

Answer (score 1):

please check out this website.
https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_sending_email.htm

Comment: How is it relevant?